# Insert DATA into Database in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to insert data in database in asp.net using c#,but it showing me this exception.

[image: exception]

Comment: Please show your code and exception message as a plain text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `table` is a preserved keyword in every ANSI SQL language. Rename your table.

Comment: Besides the above: **use parameterized queries!!!**

Answer (score 1):

It is *really* hard to tell to solve your problem on an image but my money is on `Table` is a [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) on TSQL part. You *can* use it with square brackets like `[Table]` but I do not recommend this. Change it to *non*-reserved word as a best option.

But much more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command *automatically* instead of calling `Close` method manually.

Based on your column name, `ID` should be numeric type instead of character. [Do not have a bad habit to choose wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Also do **not** store your passwords as a plain text. Read [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1054022/447156)

Comment: Thank you so very much Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Query syntax is not correct so how can you fix it?

Steps:

1. Copy command text(cmd.CommandText in debug mode)
2. Open micro soft sql server management studio and open query analyzer and paste there.
3. Run the query and you will find the cause.
4. After fixing the syntax error there now you can construct query in same way for c# code

I trust it will help you. :)